# If $540x^3 + 624x^2 - 274x - 56 = (5x + a)(bx - 7)(6x + c)$, what is $2a^2bc + 4ab^2c + abc^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a shortcut for this?

> If $540x^3 + 624x^2 - 274x - 56 = (5x + a)(bx - 7)(6x + c)$, what is $2a^2bc + 4ab^2c + abc^2$?

I am really confused on what I should do here, how should I find $a$, $b$, $c$ by only this given equation with $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Just note $$540=5\cdot b\cdot 6$$
$$624=5\cdot b\cdot c+5\cdot(-7)\cdot6+a\cdot b\cdot6$$ 
$$-274=5\cdot(-7)\cdot c+a\cdot b\cdot c+a\cdot(-7)\cdot6$$ and 
$$-56=a\cdot(-7)\cdot c.$$
Can you end it now?

I got that these values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing yopu have to do is expand the RHS, obtaining:
$$a b c x+6 a b x^2-7 a c-42 a x+5 b c x^2+30 b x^3-35 c x-210 x^2$$
From here you can equate with the LHS. In other words:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
30b=540
\\ 6ab+5bc-210=624
\\ abc-42a-35c=274
\\7ac=56
\end{matrix}\right.$$
This symple can appeare a bit messy, but we can rearrange so that it becomes:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
b=18
\\ 108a+90c-210=624
\\ 18ac-42a-35c=274
\\7ac=56
\end{matrix}\right.$$
This system has no solutions for $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the coefficient of $x^3$, we know

$$540 = (5)(b)(6)$$

i.e.

$$b=18$$

So now we know (18x-7) is a factor, $\frac{7}{18}$ must be a root. However, this is not the case, as $$540(\frac{7}{18})^3+624(\frac{7}{18})^2-274(\frac{7}{18})-56\neq 0$$